# Create array of class objects inside another class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object

I have a problem. I'm trying to create an array of different class objects derived from a base class. This is the code:

```
 class Cdvd{
protected:
 char *numeArtist; //numer artist sau film
 char *tip;// CD sau DVD
 int cantitate; //numar de CD/DVD din baza de date
 int pret; //pret per unitate
 int cod_intern; //cod intern produs. Spre exemplu 0 pentru un film horror.
 void scriereInFisier(std::fstream &out); //scriere in fisierul cu produse
public:
 Cdvd(); //constructor produs implicit
 Cdvd(const Cdvd &cdvd); //constructor produs cu parametru alt produs
 Cdvd(char *artist, char *tip, int cant, int pret, int cod_int); //constructor produs cu parametri
 ~Cdvd(); //destructor produs
 char *getNume(); //returneaza pointer la numele artistului sau filmului
 void parseFis(char *artist, char *tip, int cant, int pret, int cod_int);
 virtual void afisCamp()=0; //afiseaza campurile produsului
};


class CD : public Cdvd{
private:
 char *genMuzica; //genul muzicii
 char *extensie; //extensia fisierelor audio
 int nrTrackuri; //numar melodii
 int lungime; //lungime totala melodii
public:
 CD(); //constructor implicit cd
 CD(char *artist, int cant, int pret, int cod_int, char *genMuzica, char *extensie, int nrTrackuri, int lungime);
 CD(const CD &cd); //constructor cd cu parametru alt cd
 ~CD(); //destructor cd

 void parseFis(char *artist, int cant, int pret, int cod_int, char *genMuzica, char *extensie, int nrTrackuri, int lungime);
 void afisCamp(); //afiseaza campurile cd-ului
};

class DVD : public Cdvd{
private:
 char *genFilm;
 char *extensie;
 int lungime;
public:
 DVD();
 DVD(char *artist, int cant, int pret, int cod_int, char *genFilm, char *extensie, int lungime);
 ~DVD(){cout<<"~DVD()"<<endl;};

 void parseFis(char *artist, int cant, int pret, int cod_int, char *genFilm, char *extensie, int lungime);
 void afisCamp();
};
```

Now, I'm trying to create from this class an array of CD and DVD:

```
class ListaProduse{
 static const int dimMax=20; //dimensiune maxima lista produse
 Cdvd **vector; //vector in care se retin produsele
 int nrProduse; //retine cate produse sunt in baza de date
public:
 ListaProduse();
 ~ListaProduse();
 void adauga(std::fstream &in);
 void afisare();
};
```

and this is the code for ListaProduse class:

```
ListaProduse::ListaProduse()
{
 nrProduse=0;
 vector=new Cdvd*[dimMax];
}

ListaProduse::~ListaProduse()
{
 if(nrProduse>0)
 {
  delete vector;
 }
}

void ListaProduse::adauga(std::fstream &in)
{
 if(in.is_open())
 {
  int pret,cant,cod;
  char temp1[20],aux1[20];
  char aux;

  while(!in.eof())
  {
   in>>aux;
   in>>temp1;
   char *teemp1=new char[strlen(temp1)+1];
   strcpy(teemp1,temp1);
   in>>pret;
   in>>cant;
   in>>cod;
   switch(aux){
    case 'C':{
     int nrTr,lung;
     in>>aux1;
     char *auxiliar1=new char[strlen(aux1)+1];
     strcpy(auxiliar1,aux1);
     in>>aux1;
     char *auxiliar2=new char[strlen(aux1)+1];
     strcpy(auxiliar2,aux1);
     in>>nrTr;
     in>>lung;
     CD *x;
     x=new CD;
     x->parseFis(teemp1,pret,cant,cod,auxiliar1,auxiliar2,nrTr,lung);
     vector[nrProduse]=x;
     vector[nrProduse]->afisCamp();
     //cout<<vector[nrProduse]->numeArtist;
     nrProduse++;
     break;
        }
    case 'D':{
     int lung;
     in>>aux1;
     char *auxiliar1=new char[strlen(aux1)+1];
     strcpy(auxiliar1,aux1);
     in>>aux1;
     char *auxiliar2=new char[strlen(aux1)+1];
     strcpy(auxiliar2,aux1);
     in>>lung;
     DVD *x;
     x=new DVD;
     x->parseFis(teemp1,pret,cant,cod,auxiliar1,auxiliar2,lung);
     vector[nrProduse]=x;
     vector[nrProduse]->afisCamp();
     nrProduse++;
     break;
        }
   };
  }
 }
}

void ListaProduse::afisare()
{
 if(nrProduse>0)
  for(int i=0;i<nrProduse;i++)
  {
   this->vector[nrProduse]->afisCamp();
  }
 else
  cout<<"Nu exista produse in baza de date!"<<endl;
}
```

Now I create in main an instance of ListaProduse. I call ListaProduse.adauga(filein) and then ListaProduse.afisare(). The problem is that when I call afisare() the program stop working and says:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00ba3055 in
>   test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation
>   reading location 0xcdcdcdcd.

pointing to

> this->vector[nrProduse]->afisCamp();

What could be the problem? Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Post what you have written in ListaProduse::afisCamp() ;

Comment: There is no ListaProduse::afisCamp(); There are only Cdvd::afisCamp(), CD::afisCamp() and DVD::afisCamp().

Comment: Just got confused with names while scrolling up and down ! Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much. The problem was on

```
this->vector[nrProduse]->afiscamp();
```

It was supposed to be

```
this->vector[i]->afisCamp();
```

My mistake. :( And the idea with std::vector is more than great, but I have to do my project (for school) using polymorphism.

Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

Well, as to the actual cause of your current problem, I don't know. But I do know one thing: you're presumably writing C++, but using `char*` and other evil C-isms.

Use `std::string`, `std::vector` and the like and I assure you that your problems will go way quickly.

Comment: +1 fully agreed. by using char* and arrays, you open the path of incredibly numerous possible bugs. those bugs that no longer happen to me since I use std::string and std::vector, that take care of all the dirty work of memory and size management.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector=new Cdvd*[dimMax];
```

vector is of type  `Cdvd**`; that is, pointer to pointer to Cdvd. In the above code, you only allocated memory of type `Cdvd*`. You still need to do something like this:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < dimMax ; i++ )
    vector[i] = new Cdvd; //or new CD or new DVD;
```

After this, you can acces like `vector[i]->afisCamp()` which is what you're trying to do, by doing this:

```
this->vector[nrProduse]->afisCamp();
```

Why don't you use `std::vector<Cdvd*>`  instead? I'm talking about the STL's `vector`.

Comment: But I don't know what I am allocating. It reads data from a file and depends. It can be of type CD or DVD. The point is to create an array of CD and DVD objects, depending of the file data read.

Comment: I have added vector[nrProduse]=new CD; //or DVD  after x->parseFis(.......) and still doesn't work.

Comment: @Ionut Ungureanu: you can write the for loop accordingly, put some if/else block,and depending upon input from the file, create an array of CD and DVD. But I would still suggest to use `std::vector`

Comment: @Ionut: why don't you use `for` loop and  `i`  (from 0 to dimMax), to allocate memory, instead of doing `vector[nrProduse]=new CD;`?? what is nrProduse? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Nawaz `vector=new Cdvd*[dimMax];` What do `*` suggest in this case? I don't understand. Is it just a type cast?

Comment: Still same error. BUT When i call vector[nrProduse]->afisCamp(); after each read from the file it prints on std. The problem still occurs when I call in main ListaProduse.afisare(). I think the problem is the memory space is deallocated after I call ListaProduse.adauga(...) in main and vector[number] doesn't points to anything.

Comment: @Mahesh : vector is of type `Cdvd**`. So in that step, `*` is used to allocate memory to `pointer to pointer`.

Comment: @lonut : First change your variable type from raw pointer type to `std::vector` type. Using `std::vector` will make your life easy. It will solve many of your problem. Then you will be able to focus on the main problem!